# Is it possible for a person to stay as a full-time research faculty as long as the person is physically and mentally fit?

Tags: computer-science

Is it possible for a person to stay at a public research institution as a full-time research faculty member as long as the person is physically and mentally fit?

If so, tertiary institutions in which country offer such an advantage?

Comment: What do you mean by "forever?" Do you mean "until retirement?"

Comment: @MoisheKohan, Until physically and mentally fit, until death.

Comment: “physically and mentally fit” is not the same as “death”…. Moreover it is clear that people working at a public research institution are “faculty”?  Think of a hospital for instance.

Comment: the edit does not improve things.  “forever” is certainly not same as “physically and mentally fit”.  Presumably you mean until the person is *no longer* physically and mentally fit.  What does “physically and mentally fit” means anyways?  Who decides?

Comment: I'm guessing that the intent is until retirement. And IIRC, lots of places in Europe have mandatory retirement ages. But is the question really whether there is something like tenure that can only be cancelled for serious cause.

Comment: @Buffy, what about the USA?

Comment: @user366312, a tenured faculty member in US is "safe" until retirement (which has no fixed date, generally). A research faculty member might be tenured or on a fixed-term renewal contract, perhaps 4 years, perhaps longer.

Comment: sorry I simply don’t get what you don’t get.  Ask *a professor* if they are still fit to continue, and they will likely answer yes well after an administrator would have answered no.  so *who decides* is crucial.  Indeed I can certainly think of some professors who were unfit by any definition except their own, and stayed on.

Answer (score 3):

In principle, for the last 20-30 years, this can be possible in the U.S.

Prior to some date (which I don't recall...), there *were* mandatory retirement ages, I think state-wise or institution-wise, throughout the U.S. This affected several people I knew. But, after that point, there was no mandatory retirement.

Still, yes, physical or mental incapacity is a thing all of us will face, eventually. Moderate physical incapacity is not surprising, and need not toooo severaly impact teaching and work. Mental deterioration is a more volatile issue, and less easy to self-diagnose, apparently. In my experience,  some senior faculty who'd become unable to talk coherently about calculus had to be repeatedly "counseled" to retire. It wasn't that they were hanging on for the money, but, rather, that they absolutely did not realize that they were incoherent. Dementia is a real thing.

On a tangent, in the U.S., I do know some very good mathematicians who "voluntarily" retire, not because they're "done" doing math, but because they want to open up positions for younger people.